# Variable stored in Session ? / passing variables between JFrames

Tags: java, sql, jframe

I have two Jframes, How I can pass Variable Meno from first Jframe to 2nd Frame.
I was thinking about storing it in Session but dont know if it will work.

code on 2nd frame looks like this.

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    String Meno = login.Meno; 
    String Prispevok = jTextArea2.getText();

    try {
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(login.host + login.databaza, login.username, login.password);
        java.sql.Statement st = connection.createStatement(); 
        st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO history (`Name`, `Post`) " + "VALUES ('"+Meno+"' , '"+Prispevok+"')");
    } catch (SQLException err) {
        System.out.println(err.getMessage());
    }      
}
```

Iam sorry if iam asking wrong, but iam new in Stackoverflow. Thank you friends :)

Comment: I doubt it's a good idea to have the actual `JFrame` know the Meno value. It needs to be fed into some model, not be passed through GUI classes. What do you want to do with it exactly?

Comment: Iam creating chat app, which user has to put; username(variable Meno), and post (var Prispevok).
I need this variabales to store in MySql. and then show them in  JtextArea in JFrame

Comment: So the other frame, is it in the same program or do you start the program twice, once for each chat member?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line

```
String Meno = login.Meno;
```

makes me think you have something like

```
class Login {
    public String Meno;
}
```

with your frame declared like

```
class MyFrame {
    private Login login;
}
```

What you want is to have your `Login` class be the model of your application, which will distribute the changes. This means you don't have a `public` member, but a getter/setter methods.

```
class Login {
    private String meno;
    public void setMeno(String n) { this.meno = n; }
    public String getMeno() { return meno; }
}
```

If you want to display that name, you can do that:

```
JTextField field = new JTextField(login.getMeno());
```

Then, because the name might change, you need a mechanism for the GUI components to update. This can be done using the listener pattern:

```
interface NameListener {
    public void nameChanged(String newName);
}

class Login {
    private String meno;
    private Collection<NameListener> listeners = new ArrayList<>();
    public void addListener(NameListener l) { listeners.add(l); }
    public void setMeno(String n) {
        meno = n;
        for (NameListener l : listeners) { l.nameChanged(n); }
    }
}
```

To enable updates in your text field, you can then do

```
JTextField field = new JTextField(login.getMeno());
login.addListener(n -> field.setText(n));
```

Since you only have one `Login` instance (you should use the singleton pattern), the other frame can just register as a listener like that. Here's how you declare a singleton `Login` class:

```
class Login {
    private static final Login INSTANCE;
    private Login() {}
    public Login getInstance() {
        if (INSTANCE == null) { INSTANCE = new Login(); }
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    private String meno;
    // ...
}
```

You can then use it in your `JFrame`s like this:

```
class MyFrame {
    Login login = Login.getInstance();
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom class (that extends JFrame) where you could have methods like `public void setMeno(String meno)` and perhaps `public String getMeno()` if required so you can pass the variable to a JFrame. I'm not sure if that is what you mean since you haven't given a lot of details.

Basic example:

```
public class JFrame2 extends JFrame{
  private String meno;

  public void setMeno(String meno)
  {
    this.meno = meno;
  }
}
```

If you have a class like this, you can easily set meno inside the second JFrame by calling `setMeno(meno)` on the object you created (instance of JFrame2).

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:**
Create a class name it as Constant and store the string meno. then use wherever and whenever you want.

```
public Class Constant{
    public static String meno="";
}
```

then set the value to meno in JFrame1 like

```
Constant.meno="SomeValue";
```

then retrieve the value from that Constant in JFrame 2

```
String meno=Constant.meno;
```

**Solution 2:**
Pass the value meno in Constructor like

```
Frame2 frame=new Frame2(Meno);
```

and retrieve the meno value in JFrame2 like

```
String meno;
public Frame2(String _meno){
    meno=_meno;
}
```

hope this will help you, if you need further help just comment below.

Comment: The second solution will clash with the inherited constructor `JFrame(String title)`

Comment: @мυѕτавєւмo constructors aren't inherited like that.

Comment: I know that fact but what I'm talking about is that when the OP will desire to use that constructor it will be overriden